# Is there any browser API to get codec string from webm video?

Tags: javascript, video, webm, webcodecs, ebml

I want to extract video track's codec string from a webm video in javascript and pass it to browser's VideoDecoder configure method to decode this video.

For example: If the codec of video track in webm video is V_VP9 in the EBML formatted file but how do I extract the whole string like this 'vp09.01.20.08.01'.

So to summarise I want a codec string of video track from the webm video file in javascript.

I tried setting only 'vp09' into VideoDecoder configure but this is giving error as codec string is  ambiguous.